# Getting response header

Tags: c#, .net-core, flurl

Used the Flurl to Get response from API.

```
var response = await url.WithClient(fc)
            .WithHeader("Authorization", requestDto.ApiKey)
            .GetJsonAsync<T>();
dynamic httpResponse = response.Result;
```

But I cant able to access httpResponse.Headers

How to access response headers while using GetJsonAsync .

Comment: Do you care about the headers in all scenarios or just error responses, such as 403s? If the latter, Flurl has a handy try/catch pattern where you can get at the response headers without abandoning `GetJsonAsync`.

Answer (score 8):

You can't get a header from `GetJsonAsync<T>` because it returns `Task<T>` instead of raw response. You can call `GetAsync` and deserialize your payload at next step:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await url.GetAsync();

HttpResponseHeaders headers = response.Headers;

FooPayload payload = await response.ReadFromJsonAsync<FooPayload>();
```

`ReadFromJsonAsync` is an extention method:

```
public static async Task<TBody> ReadFromJsonAsync<TBody>(this HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    if (response.Content == null) return default(TBody);

    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TBody>(content);
}
```

P.S. This is why I prefer and recommend to use raw `HttpClient` instead of any third-party high-level client like RestSharp or Flurl.

Comment: or, you could just read the documentation of your chosen 3rd party library ;)

Comment: @Jamiec do you know a good 3rd party http client library? RestSharp is abandoned and Flurl forces to use `HttpResponseMessage` for low-level operations. I really don't see any benefits of Flurl instead of HttpClient.

Comment: I just wrote my own for my use. Its modeled a little on flurl (has a fluent interface, built mainly as extensions) because, like you, I generally dont like 3rd party libs for this simple task - but I do the same operation in very slightly different ways so it makes sense to wrap it up.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov What you're describing as a downside of Flurl ("forces you to use HttpResponseMessage for low-level operations") was actually intended to be an advantage. Flurl's main goal is modest: save keystrokes in the most common 95% of scenarios. And for the other 5%, make the underlying HttpClient APIs easily accessible (as you've demonstrated here) so that you're never stuck. (And yes, I completely made up those numbers. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could also await for the `HttpResponseMessage`, pick off the `.Headers` object, then send the completed `task` to `ReceiveJson<T>` for deserialization. Here's how to do it without an extension method:

```
var task = url.GetAsync();

HttpResponseMessage response = await task;

HttpResponseHeaders headers = response.Headers;

//Get what I need now from headers, .ReceiveJson<T>() will dispose
//response object above.

T obj = await task.ReceiveJson<T>();
```

Comment: This is the most transparent way to go, awaiting changes that will come in 3.0.